# DbContext Override SaveChanges not firing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am trying to override SaveChanges DbContect using Entity Framework.

The

> override int SaveChanges()

is not running and the break-point is not being hit.

I have moved the class into the root where the EDMX file is located but that still did not help.

How can get I the **SaveChanges override** to work?

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace DAL
{
    public class MyEntities : DbContext
    {
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            throw new Exception("override DbContext>SaveChanges working");
            // return base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**Code to call SaveChanges**

```
using (var ctx = new Entities())
            {
                // model.clientID = data.clientID;
                // model.clientGUID = data.clientGUID;
                model.clientName = data.clientName;
                model.clientDept = data.clientDept;
                model.clientWebsite = data.clientWebsite;
                model.clientEmail = data.clientEmail;
                model.isActive = data.isActive;
                model.clientModDate = data.clientModDate;
                model.clientCreatedDate = data.clientCreatedDate;

                ctx.Clients.Add(model);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
```

[image: File/Solution]
[image: code]

Comment: Are you calling the `SaveChanges()` method anywhere? Can you show the calling code?

Comment: @bassfader question updated with code example of SaveChange()

Comment: Your calling code is instantiating `Entities`, which is not the same as the `MyEntities` class you posted.

Comment: In that code you are calling the `SaveChanges()` method on the type `Entities`, but you are overriding the method on the type `MyEntities`. Looks like you are working with an abstraction Layer called `Entities`. Have you checked if the `SaveChanges()` method on `Entities` actually calls the `SaveChanges()` method on `MyEntities`?

Comment: @bassfader -- thanks!  I missed.  Code is working.

Comment: @sstan -- thanks!  I missed.  Code is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the code working using the comments provided.

1. Create the class file in the same project the EDMX is located
2. public partial class Entities <--- same name as project Entity

all working now!

https://exceptionnotfound.net/entity-change-tracking-using-dbcontext-in-entity-framework-6/

```
namespace ModelApp_MVC.Models
{
    public partial class Entities : DbContext
    {
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            //Do custom code
            // throw new Exception("override DbContext>SaveChanges working");
            // this.SaveChanges();


            var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

            foreach (var change in modifiedEntities)
            {
                var entityName = change.Entity.GetType().Name;
                var primaryKey = GetPrimaryKeyValue(change);

                foreach (var prop in change.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
                {
                    var originalValue = change.OriginalValues[prop].ToString();
                    var currentValue = change.CurrentValues[prop].ToString();
                    if (originalValue != currentValue) //Only create a log if the value changes
                    {
                        ChangeLog log = new ChangeLog()
                {
                    EntityName = entityName,
                    PrimaryKeyValue = primaryKey.ToString(),
                    PropertyName = prop,
                    OldValue = originalValue,
                    NewValue = currentValue,
                    DateChanged = now
                };
                ChangeLogs.Add(log);
                    }
                }
            }
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }

        object GetPrimaryKeyValue(DbEntityEntry entry)
        {
            var objectStateEntry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity);
            return objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way: the EF class is defined with "partial".  So add another class file with the class name being:

```
public partial class MyEntities
{
   public void SavingChanges()
   {
      //Do custom code

      this.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

And change all of your `SaveChanges()` calls to `SavingChanges()`.  Then you can customize the process however you want.  The key is to add another partial class so make sure the EF context has the partial defined (not in your code sample but was the default implementation).